# BeautifulSoup in Python - getting the n-th tag of a type

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have some html code that contains many `<table>`s in it.

I'm trying to get the information in the second table. Is there a way to do this without using `soup.findAll('table')` ?

When I do use `soup.findAll('table')`, I get an error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Is there a way to get the n-th tag in some code or another way that does not require going through all the tables? Or should I see if I can add titles to the tables? (like `<table title="things">`)

There are also headers (`<h4>title</h4>`) above each table, if that helps.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Here's what I was thinking when I asked the question:

I was unpacking the objects into two values, when there were many more. I thought this would just give me the first two things from the list, but of course, it kept giving me the error mentioned above. I was unaware the return value was a list and thought it was a special object or something and I was basing my code off of my friends'.

I was thinking this error meant there were too many tables on the page and that it couldn't handle all of them, so I was asking for a way to do it without the method I was using. I probably should have stopped assuming things.

Now I know it returns a list and I can use this in a for loop or get a value from it with `soup.findAll('table')[someNumber]`. I learned what unpacking was and how to use it, as well. Thanks everyone who helped.

Hopefully that clears things up, now that I know what I'm doing my question makes less sense than it did when I asked it, so I thought I'd just put a note here on what I was thinking.

**EDIT 2:**

This question is now pretty old, but I still see that I was never really clear about what I was doing.

If it helps anyone, I was attempting to unpack the `findAll(...)` results, of which the amount of them I didn't know.

```
useless_table, table_i_want, another_useless_table = soup.findAll("table");
```

Since there weren't always the amount of tables I had guessed in the page, and all the values in the tuple need to be unpacked, I was receiving the `ValueError`:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

So, I was looking for the way to grab the second (or whichever index) table in the tuple returned without running into errors about how many tables were used.

Comment: *Just* doing `soup.findAll('table')` does *not* cause a `ValueError`. Please post your full code. `too many values to unpack` means you have multiple variables on the left-hand-side expression.

Comment: `soup.find(title="things")` ??

Comment: At the top of the post I said that I was using it on code with many `<table>`s in it. I'm using it on this page: view-source:http://dhmc.us/players/view/nasonfish/ and am using this code: `table1, table2 = soup.find_all('table')`

Comment: `soup.find_all('table')` returns a list. `tables = soup.find_all('table')` should work

Comment: @nasonfish: The error shows you have more than 2 tables, so the unpack fails. Don't use tuple unpacking in this case.

Comment: @Aamir Adnan that code is not in the page yet. I was seeing if that would be the best way to do it, or if there was another way. sorry if I was confusing

Comment: @Martijn Pieters oh, okay, thanks. I wasn't exactly sure what the error meant, I guess. I'll try that now, thanks. Thanks for all your speedy responses, everyone.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To get the second table from the call `soup.findAll('table')`, use it as a list, just index it:

```
secondtable = soup.findAll('table')[1]
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks! Not sure why I didn't think of this before.

Comment: What does `findAll('table')[1]` really mean? It just find the second table or find all the tables first and then get the second table?

Comment: @CokileChui  It  finds all the tables first and then get the second table. FindAll is a function and its return value gives a list and then we get the second element of it

Answer (score 2):

Martjin Pieter's answer will make it work indeed. I had some experience with nested `table` tag which broke my code when I just simply get the second table in the list without paying attention.

When you try to `find_all` and get the nth element, there is a potential you will mess up, you had better locate the first element you want and make sure the n-th element is actually a sibling of that element instead of children.

1. You can use the `find_next_sibling()` to secure your code
2. you can find the parent first and then use find_all(recursive=False) to guarantee your search range.

Just in case you need it. I will list my code below(use recursive=FALSE).

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = """
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <p>Table1</p>
            <table>
                <p>Extra Table</p>
            </table>
        </table>
        <table>
            <p>Table2</p>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(text)

tables = soup.find('body').find_all('table')
print len(tables)
print tables[1].text.strip()
#3
#Extra Table # which is not the table you want without warning

tables = soup.find('body').find_all('table', recursive=False)
print len(tables)
print tables[1].text.strip()
#2
#Table2 # your desired output
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my version

```
# Import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Read your HTML
#html_doc = your html

# Get BS4 object
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "lxml")

# Find next Sibling Table to H3 Header with text "THE GOOD STUFF"    
the_good_table = soup.find(name='h3', text='THE GOOD STUFF').find_next_sibling(name='table')

# Find Second tr in your table
your_tr = the_good_table.findAll(name='tr')[1]

# Find Text Value of First td in your tr
your_string = your_tr.td.text

print(your_string)
```

Output:

```
'I WANT THIS STRING'
```